# Add BCC recipient to Completed Renewal Order notification in WooCommerce Subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to add a BCC recipient to a specific type of mail sent by WooCommerce. This concerns the customers that receive a renewal mail. The type of the mail is 'Completed Renewal Order'.

I am aware of this post: [How to add BCC recipient to all emails sent by WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52924180/11192771) which discusses adding a BCC to every mail sent by WooCommerce.

The solution for that problem was found as:

```
function add_bcc_all_emails( $headers, $object ) {

    $headers = array( 
         $headers,
         'Bcc: Me <my@mail.net>' ."\r\n",
    );

    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_bcc_all_emails', 10, 2 );
```

I would like to edit this code, so we can add a BCC to the 'Completed Renewal Orders' only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following revisited code, to target Completed Renewal Order email notification, while adding a Bcc recipient:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_bcc_to_completed_renewal_order_notification', 10, 2 );
function add_bcc_to_completed_renewal_order_notification( $headers, $email_id ) {
    if( $email_id === 'customer_completed_renewal_order' ) {
        $full_name = 'Mr Someone';
        $email     = 'my@mail.net';

        $headers  .= sprintf("Bcc: %s\r\n",  utf8_decode($full_name.' <'.$email.'>') );
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Related: [Target a specific email notification with the email id in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741577/targeting-specific-email-with-the-email-id-in-woocommerce/47742782)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a condition to send email only in a specific condition, so change your code to:

```
function add_bcc_all_emails( $headers, $object ) {
   if ($object == 'completed_renewal_orders') {  // replace with correct slug for Completed Renewal Orders
       $headers = array( 
          $headers,
          'Bcc: Me <my@mail.net>' ."\r\n",
      );
    }
    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_bcc_all_emails', 10, 2 );
```